# How to get values in textboxes based on value seleted in drop-down list in jsp

Tags: jsp

I am trying to `populate values` to `textbox` from database based on selected item in `combo box`,it worked, but when ever i select the value and the `textbox` is populated,it inserts the form values to database without `submitting` the form values. Please can anyone help me out.

This is my code below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function reset(){
           alert("Yeah!");
           document.getElementByID("subzone").value = "";
       }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.history.forward();
        function noback() { window.history.forward(); }
     </script>


       <script type="text/javascript">
           function myoriginaldata() {
              document.getElementById("gn").value = document.getElementById("hgn").value; 
              document.getElementById("mn").value = document.getElementById("hmn").value;
              document.getElementById("ag").value = document.getElementById("hag").value; 
          }
  </script>
   <body>
    <form action="/FeezyMusic/B_book_artist" method="post" class="form-horizontal row-fluid">

                    <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Select Artist to book here...</label>
            <div class="controls">
                            <select tabindex="1" name="group_name" id="gid" onchange="this.form.submit()" data-placeholder="Select here.." class="span8">
                            <option>Select</option>
                            <%
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/feezymusic","root","");
            sqlQuery = "Select * from bookartist";
            st = conn.createStatement();
            rst = st.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
            while (rst.next()) {
               %>
               <option><%=rst.getString("ARTISTNAME")%></option>
            <%
            }
            rst.close();
            st.close();
            conn.close();

            %>
        </select>

        </div>
        </div>

            <%
            groupname_var=request.getParameter("group_name");
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/feezymusic","root","");
                sqlQuery="select ArtistGenre,ArtistManager,Agent from bookartist where ArtistName='"+groupname_var+"'";
                st=conn.createStatement();
                rst=st.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
                while(rst.next())
                {
                data_genre=rst.getString("ArtistGenre");
                data_manager = rst.getString("ArtistManager");
                data_agent = rst.getString("Agent");
                }
                rst.close();
                st.close();
                conn.close();

            %>
            <input type="hidden" id="hgroupname_id" value="<%=groupname_var%>">

    <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Artist Genre</label>
            <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" id="basicinput" name="genre" value="<%=data_genre%>"  placeholder="Artist..." class="span8" disabled>
            </div>
        </div>  


<div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Artist Manager</label>
            <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="manager" value="<%=data_manager%>" id="basicinput" placeholder="Manager..." class="span8" disabled>
            </div>
        </div>                    

 <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Feezy Music Agent</label>
            <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="agent" value="<%=data_agent%>" id="basicinput" placeholder="Agent..." class="span8" disabled>
            </div>
        </div>


<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
        </div>



                        <%

            String genre_var = request.getParameter("genre");
            String manager_var = request.getParameter("manager");
            String agent_var = request.getParameter("agent");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/feezymusic","root","");
            st=conn.createStatement();
         %>
           <input type="hidden" id="hgn" value="<%=genre_var%>">             
           <input type="hidden" id="hmn" value="<%=manager_var%>">            
           <input type="hidden" id="hag" value="<%=agent_var%>">            

           <% 
                if(groupname_var!=null && genre_var!=null && manager_var!=null && agent_var!=null){
                    if(!groupname_var.equals("") && !genre_var.equals("") && !manager_var.equals("") && !agent_var.equals("")){
                        %>
                   <script type="text/javascript">
                   myoriginaldata();
                 </script>  
                 <% 
                      st.executeUpdate("update bookartist set ArtistGenre='"+genre_var+"',ArtistManager='"+manager_var+"',Agent='"+agent_var+"' where ArtistName='"+groupname_var+"'");

                    }
                }
               st.close();
               conn.close();

               %>
               <script type="text/javascript">
                document.getElementById("gid").value = document.getElementById("hgroupname_id").value;
            </script>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have given `onchange="this.form.submit()"` to your `select box` ,so whenever the value of `select` is changed form will get **[submitted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit)** by default.To avoid this , just change your code like below :

```
    <select tabindex="1" name="group_name" id="gid" 
onchange="myfunction(this.value);" data-placeholder="Select here.." class="span8">        
     <!--^added this function and passing value to it-->
    ..
     </select>
```

Now in your `<script></script>` do like below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunction(values)
{
 document.getElementById("yourtextboxid").value=values; //<--assigning value of select to textbox

}
</script>
```

Update 1 :

---

Now to get selected value from database , you can use `ajax` .because here you don't want to submit your `form` .Now your `script` will look like below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction(values) {
        document.getElementById("yourtextboxid").value=values; //<--assigning value of select to textbox
    //ajax call
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
         request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
         request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }

     request.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
             //do something
             alert("success");
             document.getElementById("yourdivid").innerHTML = this.responseText;
         }
     };
     //sending group_name on jsp page
     request.open("GET", "yourjsppage?group_name="+values, true);
     request.send(); 
    }
</script>
```

Also add a check for `null` value i.e

```
<%
        if(request.getParameter("group_name") ! = null ){ 
        //your db code 
     groupname_var=request.getParameter("group_name");
               Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/feezymusic","root","");
                    sqlQuery="select ArtistGenre,ArtistManager,Agent from bookartist where ArtistName='"+groupname_var+"'";
                    st=conn.createStatement();
                    rst=st.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
                    while(rst.next())
                    {
                    String data_genre=rst.getString("ArtistGenre");
                    String data_manager = rst.getString("ArtistManager");
                    String data_agent = rst.getString("Agent");
                    }

                    rst.close();
                    st.close();
                    conn.close();


     //whatever will be in out.println() will be sent back as response 
           out.println("<input type='hidden' id='hgroupname_id' value='"+groupname_var+"'>

            <div class='control-group'>
                    <label class='control-label' for='basicinput'>Artist Genre</label>
                    <div class='controls'>
                                    <input type='text' id='basicinput' name='genre' value='"+data_genre+"'  placeholder='Artist...' class='span8' disabled>
                    </div>
                </div>  


        <div class='control-group'>
                    <label class='control-label' for='basicinput'>Artist Manager</label>
                    <div class='controls'>
                    <input type='text' name='manager' value='"+data_manager+"' id='basicinput' placeholder='Manager...' class='span8' disabled>
                    </div>
                </div>                    
         <div class='control-group'>
                    <label class='control-label' for='basicinput'>Feezy Music Agent</label>
                    <div class='controls'>
                    <input type='text' name='agent' value='"+data_agent+"' id='basicinput' placeholder='Agent...' class='span8' disabled>
                    </div>
                </div>");

        }
   %>
```

Also , in your currrent jsp page add an `<div></div>`to replace data inside it with the response of `ajax` . i.e :

```
<!--adding div with id to jsp page-->
<div id="yourdivid">
<input type="hidden" id="hgroupname_id" value="<%=groupname_var%>">

    <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="basicinput">Artist Genre</label>
            <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" id="basicinput" name="genre" value="<%=data_genre%>"  placeholder="Artist..." class="span8" disabled>
            </div>
        </div>  
..
.....
            <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="agent" value="<%=data_agent%>" id="basicinput" placeholder="Agent..." class="span8" disabled>
            </div>
        </div> 
</div>           
<!--closing div-->
```

Comment: Thank you. i tried your code, but it's not fetching the values from database related to the selected item in the drop down list,it is just setting the text box field to the selected drop down item

Comment: You can use `ajax` for that , check updated answer .

Comment: Sorry please,can you show me a full code sample of getting values in text boxes based on selected drop down list from database

Comment: Now check updated answer , you can do above with `json` as well ,.